# CustomCell with Delegate method crashes my app

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates, tableview, parse-platform

My app uses parse.com, and I created a custom cell that contains a delegate.

FFCustomCellWithImage.h:

```
@ class FFCustomCellWithImage;
@ protocol FFCustomCellWithImageDelegate <NSObject>

- (Void) cellaImmagine: (FFCustomCellWithImage *) cellaImmagine userPressedGoPointButtonAction: (UIButton *) goPointButton goPointObject: (PFObject *) goPointObject sender: (id) sender;

@ end

@ interface FFCustomCellWithImage: UITableViewCell
@ property (nonatomic, weak) id <FFCustomCellWithImageDelegate> delegate;
```

When I go to execute the method, the app crashes and I do not understand why. What am I doing wrong?

The breakpoint show this: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code =1,address=0x50497265)

The breakpoint stops on this line:

```
-(void)cellaImmagine:(FFCustomCellWithImage *)cellaImmagine userPressedGoPointButtonAction:(UIButton *)goPointButton goPointObject:(PFObject *)goPointObject sender:(id)sender
```

This is the method implemented in the class where there is the Tableview:

FFTimeline.m:

```
#import "FFTimeline.h"
#import "FFCustomCellTimelineSocial.h"
#import "FFCustomCellWithImage.h"
#import "FFQueryCostanti.h"

@interface FFTimeline ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) PFObject *PostDetails;

@end



    -(void)cellaImmagine:(FFCustomCellWithImage *)cellaImmagine userPressedGoPointButtonAction:(UIButton *)goPointButton goPointObject:(PFObject *)goPointObject sender:(id)sender {

        self.PostDetails = [self.ArrayforPost objectAtIndex:[sender tag]];

        goPointObject = self.PostDetails;

        [cellaImmagine setGoPointButtonStatus:NO];

        BOOL GoPointAssigned = !goPointButton.selected;
        [cellaImmagine setGoPointStatus:GoPointAssigned];

        NSString *initialNumberButton = goPointButton.titleLabel.text;
        NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale  alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"it_IT"]];
        NSNumber *numeroGoPointAssegnati = [formatter  numberFromString:goPointButton.titleLabel.text];

        if (GoPointAssigned) {
            numeroGoPointAssegnati = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[numeroGoPointAssegnati intValue] +1];
            [self SaveGoPointAssegnatiClass:sender];
        }

        else {
            if ([numeroGoPointAssegnati intValue] > 0) {
                numeroGoPointAssegnati = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[numeroGoPointAssegnati intValue] -1];
                [self DeleteGoPointToPostClass:sender];
            }
        }
        [goPointButton setTitle:[formatter stringFromNumber:numeroGoPointAssegnati] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


        if (GoPointAssigned) {
            [FFCustomCellWithImage assegnaGoPointPost:goPointObject block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                FFCustomCellWithImage *actualHeaderView = (FFCustomCellWithImage *)[self tableView:self.FFTableView viewForHeaderInSection:goPointButton.tag];
                [actualHeaderView setGoPointButtonStatus:YES];
                [actualHeaderView setGoPointStatus:succeeded];

                if (!succeeded) {
                    [actualHeaderView.AddGoPoint setTitle:initialNumberButton forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                }
            }];

        } else {
            [FFCustomCellWithImage eliminaGoPointPost:goPointObject block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                FFCustomCellWithImage *actualHeaderView = (FFCustomCellWithImage *)[self tableView:self.FFTableView  viewForHeaderInSection:goPointButton.tag];
                [actualHeaderView setGoPointButtonStatus:YES];
                [actualHeaderView setGoPointStatus:!succeeded];

                if (!succeeded) {
                    [actualHeaderView.AddGoPoint setTitle:initialNumberButton forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                }
            }];

        }

    }
```

Comment: Could you please post the error message?

Comment: When the app crashes NSLog returns no error but I added a breakpoint exception and shows me this line

- (void) cellaImmagine: (FFCustomCellWithImage *) cellaImmagine userPressedGoPointButtonAction: (UIButton *) goPointButton goPointObject: (PFObject *) goPointObject sender: (id) sender

   and the following message EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1, address = 0x50497265)

Comment: I don't know if this is a problem, but you have the method declared with "Void" with a capital "V", whereas you're implementing it with a lowercase v.

Comment: no ... not 'what the problem ... V The capital is the fault of the translator - ... sorry ...

Comment: Where do you set the delegate?  Do you have Zombie Objects enabled in the scheme?

Comment: you have zombies ... and the delegate is set in the Custom Cell .. I'm getting crazy to do all that they can to change my image button when clicked .. until now still have not managed to reach my goal ... awesome is not able to resolve something so simple ...